# Made two edits within two minutes, but they weren't merged

Tags: support, editing

I'm used to editing then noticing something small I missed and quickly editing again. Normally the second edit is merged with the first as long as it's within a grace period of 5 minutes, but I just now [edited this post twice](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1122748/revisions) within two minutes (18:54 and 18:56 UTC, repectively) and the edits were not merged. Why did these edits not get merged? Did the grace period change, or is this a minor bug?

Comment: See linked duplicate. The comment that ended the grace period is [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122748/install-openoffice-on-ubuntu-mate#comment1857040_1122748)

Comment: I guess not only comments but votes (up/down) also ends grace period. Happened once or twice in my case.

Comment: @Kulfy Huh, I guess that makes sense when you think about it, cause a vote gets locked in after a certain time, and can only be changed it if the post is edited.

Comment: You can find this [answer on meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251876/172297) by Shog about the grace period. Votes don't seem to matter according to that answer.